# Wondering about classes in arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have a script with the following code:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class app {
    public static int p;
    public static int b=0;
    public static int i;
    public static int add;

    public static List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static List<Node> c = new ArrayList<Node>();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random rand = new Random();


        for( i = 0;i<=10;i++){
            int random = getRandom();
            if(random!=0){
        a.add(random);
            }else if(random == 0){

            }
        }
        Collections.sort(a);
        System.out.println(a);

        for(int z = 1;z<a.size();z++){
        Node n = new Node();
            Node.pos=a.get(z);
            System.out.println("Node pos set to "+a.get(z));
            c.add(n);
            System.out.println("Node at " + n.pos);

        }

        System.out.println("class array length " + c.size());
        System.out.println("Node at index " + 0 +" has a pos of " + c.get(0).pos);



    }

    public static int getRandom(){
        Random randd = new Random();
        int randomnum = randd.nextInt(10);
        if(!a.contains(randomnum)){
        return randomnum;
        }else if(a.contains(randomnum)){

        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now what I'm trying to accomplish with this, is I want the Node `n` that's created to be added to an array, which holds all the nodes and their positions. But it seems like once I create another node, all the nodes before it change their pos to that one.

For example, I can try `c.get(0).pos` and it will return the same number as the one at 9, or however big the array is. How do I make every node that's added to the array keep its values? What's the problem?

Comment: You never actually set the property of the object you create.  It looks like you're setting a static member for some reason.

Comment: Debug it yourself using your IDE's debugger. Learning to do that is far more valuable than any answer that may be given.

Answer (score 5):

Your pos field in Node is static, which we can see since you're accessing it on the class not the instance. Make it a non-static instance variable. Also even if it were a non-static field, you should avoid accessing fields directly but rather should use setter and getter methods.

For instance, don't do:

```
Node n = new Node();
Node.pos=a.get(z);  // a static access on the class
```

but rather:

```
Node n = new Node();
n.setPos(a.get(z));  // a non-static setter method call on the instance
```

Comment: If I do that then I can't access it from the other class?

Comment: @user2680805: yes you can. You access it on the *instance* not on the Node class. You're accessing it wrong and fixing the wrong thing.